# Is the following a semiring?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $f: X' \rightarrow X$ be any map and $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ a semring. Is $f^{-1}(\mathcal{H})$ a semiring?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of function is $f$?

Comment: We don't have any restrictions.

Comment: Then I don't think it is, what do you mean precisely by $X'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer a [semiring](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semiring_of_Sets) $\mathcal{H}$ on set $X$ is  a non-empty
collection of subsets of $X$ such that $A,B\in\mathcal{H}$ implies
that $A\cap B\in\mathcal{H}$ and secondly that $A-B$ can be written
as a finite union of disjoint elements of $\mathcal{H}$. In this
context let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ a function. Then we have:

- $f^{-1}\left(A\right)\cap f^{-1}\left(B\right)=f^{-1}\left(A\cap B\right)$
- $f^{-1}\left(A\right)-f^{-1}\left(B\right)=f^{-1}\left(A-B\right)$
- $f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}f^{-1}\left(A_{i}\right)$ and if the $A_i$ are disjoint then so are the $f^{-1}\left(A_{i}\right)$.

This tells us the $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{H}\right)$ is also a semiring. Preimages are (unlike images) very cooperative.